# How can I use regular expressions in react js so that I can you use that in firestore collection name

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, react-router

So I am writing in functional components, I want an expression so that I can retrive that expression collection from firestore database.
So here's the problem.
I need a Six lettered word in which the last three letters should a specific .. eg, CSE
like

group = "CSE"

regExpre = ***+group

//
db.collection({regExpre})

Answer (score 1):

First, you should use [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) constructor function if the `group` is dynamic

The below image is specific to `CES` at the end. It could be anything

[image]

```js
const str = "itiCSE",
  group = "CSE";
let regex = new RegExp(`^[a-zA-Z]{3}${group}$`);

console.log(regex.test(str));
```

Answer (score 0):

you are in the right direction,
the regular expression is:

```
/^[a-zA-Z]{3}(CES)$/g
```